# Order schema not showing right on Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to implement the Order schema as presented on : https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Order",
  "merchant": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Test Ltd."
  },
  "orderNumber": "56d59b633427b",
  "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/PaymentComplete",
  "acceptedOffer": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemOffered": {
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Test Products"
    },
    "price": "41.09",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "eligibleQuantity": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "value": "1"
    },
    "url": "http://project1.local/account/tickets",
    "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "ViewAction",
      "target": "http://project1.local/account/tickets"
    }
  }}
</script>
```

The issue is that the email shows like a normal email. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

PS: The code validates on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the JSON I've posted below. PaymentComplete is not recognized, so I used OrderDelivered. You can find more info here:

https://schema.org/OrderStatus

I noticed the word "tickets" in your URL, are you intending to use the order schema for ticket confirmations? I would suggest using [event reservation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) instead. Using this will integrate with [Google Now cards](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards/) and also input the event into the user's Calendar. You can still generate a action button by using url or modifyReservationurl.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Order",
  "merchant": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Test Ltd."
  },
  "orderNumber": "56d59b633427b",
  "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderDelivered",
  "priceCurrency": "USD",
  "price": "41.00",
  "acceptedOffer": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemOffered": {
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Test Products"
    },
    "price": "41.00",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "eligibleQuantity": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "value": "1"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://project1.local/account/tickets",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "target": "https://project1.local/account/tickets"
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]